# Clone List of Dimensions and do Math on Clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm trying to use jquery to clone a list. Something like this:

```
<div class="copy-me">
  <!-- dimensions in Inches -->
  <a href="11x14.html" class="list-group-item" slug="11x14">11x14 Inches</a>
  <a href="18x24.html" class="list-group-item" slug="18x24">18x24 Inches</a>
  ...etc
</div>
<div class="paste-here">
  <!-- generate, clone dimensions in CM -->
</div>
```

My list is comprised of numerous dimensions, in Inches (paper sizes). I use some Math to change Inches to CM. The maths is simple.

What I'm having an issue with is cloning this list (I use the attribute 'slug' to grab the plain text dimensions > do the math > clone the list) to a new div named .paste_here. When I paste it also edits the values of a separate list on the same page.

**How do I specifically run the math ONLY on the items I wish to clone?**

This is my code so far:

```
var $theClone = $(".copy-me").clone();
$theClone.find('a').each(function() {
  var selctedSizeB = $theClone.find(this).attr('slug');
  var selctedSizeArrayB = selctedSizeB.split('x');
  var heightCM = (Math.round(selctedSizeArrayB[0] / 0.39370));
  var widthCM = (Math.round(selctedSizeArrayB[1] / 0.39370));

  $("a[slug='" + $(this).attr('slug') + "']").text(heightCM + "×" + widthCM +"cm");
});     
$(".paste-here").html($theClone);
```

I also need to incorporate an instance of `.replace('-', '.')` some of my slugs show dimensions with a hyphen rather than a period, which breaks the maths. Any pointers most welcome.

Comment: `$(this).text(...)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replaced append code into each() function in order to append new a tags before setting new text to it. In addition, in order to define a tags locate in which div element, I changed the code `$("a[slug='" + $(this).attr('slug') + "']").text(heightCM + "×" + widthCM +"cm");`
        to this one: `$(this).parent().find("a[slug='" + $(this).attr('slug') + "']").text(heightCM + "×" + widthCM +"cm");`
the final code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#btn", function(){
      $theClone = $(".copy-me").clone().removeClass('copy-me');

      $theClone.find('a').each(function() {
        $(".paste-here").append($(this).parent());
        var selctedSizeB = $(this).attr('slug');
        var selctedSizeArrayB = selctedSizeB.split('x');
        var heightCM = (Math.round(selctedSizeArrayB[0] / 0.39370));
        var widthCM = (Math.round(selctedSizeArrayB[1] / 0.39370));

        $(this).parent().find("a[slug='" + $(this).attr('slug') + "']").text(heightCM + "×" + widthCM +"cm");
      });
    });

 });
```

```html
<div class="copy-me">
  <!-- dimensions in Inches -->
  <a href="11x14.html" class="list-group-item" slug="11x14">11x14 Inches</a>

  <a href="18x24.html" class="list-group-item" slug="18x24">18x24 Inches</a>
</div>
<div class="paste-here">
  <!-- generate, clone dimensions in CM -->
</div>
<button id="btn">clone</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: What have you changed, why have you changed it, and why does it solve the problem? "Try this code" answers aren't as helpful as you think. Teach, don't tell.

Comment: @alisher-nasrullayev thanks so much, I look forward to comparing your code to my existing mess and in the process I'll learn from your knowledge! that's how it tends to go in my case... as I'm not a full time programmer or coder of any calibre. I'll update this as 'solved' shortly if all goes well!